# Select sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a query with a condition but it is returning an empty result even though I have the data that matches these conditions. I am a beginner, so I'm not sure if this query is correct.

```
public Cursor raw() {    
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String select = "SELECT * FROM table_person WHERE data >= " + SelecionarPeriodo.dataInicial + " AND " + "data <=" + SelecionarPeriodo.dataFinal;

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery( select, new String[]{});
    Log.i("String", select);

    return res;
}
```

[image]

If I remove this condition and use a query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM table_person
```

I have the results and the columns corresponding to the dates I'm trying to get.

Comment: What is your data type of the `data` field?

Comment: data is of the text type

Comment: What is `SelecionarPeriodo.dataInicial` and `SelecionarPeriodo.dataFinal`?

Comment: SelecionarPeriodo.dataInicial and SelecionarPeriodo.dataFinal are Strings with the data text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have written your query you are actually comparing the column `data` with `0`, because a value like `14/12/2020` is considered as an expression containing divisions between the numbers `14`, `12` and `2020` which has `0` as result.

If you want to compare dates in SQLite you must use a comparable format like `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is the only valid text date format for SQLite.
So if you stored the dates in the column `data` in any other format you'd better change it to `YYYY-MM-DD`.
You must also use the same format for the parameters `SelecionarPeriodo.dataInicial` and `SelecionarPeriodo.dataFinal` which will be compared to `data`.

Then use the recommended and safe way to pass the parameters in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
public Cursor raw() {    
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String select = "SELECT * FROM table_person WHERE data >= ? AND data <= ?" + ;
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(select, new String[]{SelecionarPeriodo.dataInicial, SelecionarPeriodo.dataFinal});
    Log.i("String", select);
    return res;
}
```